# Handling zip files via media browser

Tags: drupal-7, zip, wysiwyg, media

I am using media module with wysiwyg integration of media browser.

I need to create a new file type (say zip) and have custom formatters for this file type. So, whenever a zip file is uploaded via media browser, i want it to get associated with "zip" file type and the formatters should be applied to it as selected by the user.

Tried to look for some tutorials but not much of help. Can someone please guide me through with this?

Thanks.